# How to PartitionBy (SQL) to rank on RStudio

Tags: r

So I have something like this:

```
data.frame(content = c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),
           eje = c("politics","sports","education","sports","health","politics"),
           value = c(3,2,1,2,1,1))
```

And I'd like to group by `content` and keep the values in `eje` that has the highest value on `value`, and to keep both values when it ties.

So on sample I'd stay with:

```
data.frame(content = c("a","b","c","c"),
           eje = c("politics","sports","health","politics"),
           value = c(3,2,1,1))`
```

On SQL I'd do something like RANK OVER PARTITION BY (content, DESC value) and then filter rows with value "1" on the RANK column created.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = data.frame(content = c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),
           eje = c("politics","sports","education","sports","health","politics"),
           value = c(3,2,1,2,1,1))

library(dplyr)
d %>%
  group_by(content) %>%
  slice_max(value)
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
# # Groups:   content [3]
#   content eje      value
#   <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 a       politics     3
# 2 b       sports       2
# 3 c       health       1
# 4 c       politics     1
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[dt[, .I[value == max(value)], by=content]$V1]
```

Output:

```
   content      eje value
1:       a politics     3
2:       b   sports     2
3:       c   health     1
4:       c politics     1
```